# Securing a removable drive when sharing

Tags: windows-7, external-hard-drive

I have a removable drive that I share across my network.  If I remove the "Everyone" and "User" groups, and then my computer dies, am I still going to be able to access that data by unplugging the drive and attaching it to another machine?

I'm using Windows 7 Professional as my OS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you will still be able to access you files, simply take ownership of the files as the local administrator on the remote computer. Just make sure you don't have the data encrypted.

Comment: Thanks.  How do you make sure the data is not encrypted?  That's what happened the last time I lost data this way.

Comment: @Russell Steen If you right click on properties and look where it says "read only" and "hidden" there is an advanced button. Under advanced there is a check box that says, "Encrypt contents to secure data" just make sure that is unchecked.